# What are benefit to use doctype DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.0//EN over XHTML 1.0 Strict?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

In some sites on web I noticed they are using this doctype. What is this doctype and what is the benefit of this Doctype `XHTML+RDFa`?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.0//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-1.dtd'>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xmlns:v="http://rdf.data-vocabulary.org/#" xml:lang='en' dir='ltr'>
 <head profile="http://purl.org/uF/2008/03/">
```

Answer (score 3):

Basically RDFa is 'Rich snippets and structured markup', it'll allow crawlers to understand the content on your page.

Google explains it best:
http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=146898

Sounds like Rich Snippets will be the future of SEO in enough sites start to use them.

Google also has built a testing tool for reading Rich Snippets: http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets

Here's a list of sites already using RDFa:
http://rdfa.info/wiki/Examples-in-the-wild

Comment: @metal-gear-solid ya just different syntax, not sure what the benefits are vs RDFa other than W3 seems to been giving it more attention

Answer (score 1):

RDF basically allows the page to be annotated with machine-readable markup. This is a concept known as "semantic web" or "linked data" (see this [Ted Talk](http://www.ted.com/talks/tim_berners_lee_on_the_next_web.html)). The use of machine-readable formats enables all sorts of possibilities by enhancing the amount and quality of data that are available to applications.

Comment: Is it better than XHTML 1.0 Strict? What is the difference between making site with XHTML 1.0 Strict and XHTML+RDFa?

Comment: You would use XHTML+RDFa in order to gain access to the RDF features.

Comment: What are RDF features which can be useful for any site?

Comment: What's with the downvote? If the answer is wrong or inaccurate, then downvote, but if you just don't like it or you don't find it complete enough, then simply don't upvote.

Answer (score 0):

See the spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/rdfa-syntax/

> RDF/XML [RDF-SYNTAX] provides
>   sufficient flexibility to represent
>   all of the abstract concepts in RDF
>   [RDF-CONCEPTS]. However, it presents a
>   number of challenges; first it is
>   difficult or impossible to validate
>   documents that contain RDF/XML using
>   XML Schemas or DTDs, which therefore
>   makes it difficult to import RDF/XML
>   into other markup languages.

Comment: Hmm I also found this article "Serving XHTML+RDFa properly isn't really possible" http://rayofsolaris.net/blog/2009/serving-xhtml-rdfa but i saw some which are valid in W3C validator. "This document was successfully checked as XHTML + RDFa!"

Comment: I'd trust the w3.org spec over some random blog any day. It says it's difficult/impossible to validate, so the blog post probably has some truth to it, but it is possible.

Comment: w3.org/TR/xhtml-rdfa-primer/ : To date, because XHTML is extensible while HTML is not, RDFa has only been specified for XHTML 1.1. Web publishers are welcome to use RDFa markup inside HTML4: the design of RDFa anticipates this use case, and most RDFa parsers will recognize RDFa attributes in any version of HTML. The authors know of no deployed Web browser that will fail to present an HTML document as intended after adding RDFa markup to the document. However, publishers should be aware that RDFa will not validate in HTML4 at this time. RDFa attributes validate in XHTML, using XHTML1.1+RDFa DTD